# Install angularjs ui.router with bower

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs I want to use the ui-router with bower. 
I have added the following line to my bower.json

```
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15"
```

the I have ran

```
bower install
```

I want to include the module in my index.html but I don't know which path to use.

Comment: Do bower install angular-ui-router  in your console.
Then search  angular-ui-router.min.js and do  <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
Ref: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 4):

By default bower installs packages inside `bower_components` directory. Make sure that this directory is web accessible. You can then include the script from:

`bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js`

You can also change the default `bower_components` directory by setting a new value in your [`.bowerrc`](http://bower.io/docs/config/) file as:

```
{
    "directory": "./foo/bar"
}
```

This way bower will install packages inside `foo/bar` path instead of the default `bower_components`

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal, go to project path.Use command,

$ bower install angular-ui-router

Comment: Why would OP need to run `bower install angular-ui-router`? They've already added the dependency and run `bower install`

Comment: Welcome to SO. A fuller answer as to why this is needed would be helpful.